# Linux statistics script (Google analytics-like)

Tags: logs, users, monitoring, load

We own a few servers, each with about 100 users on it, some with 1 domain, some with a few.
I'm looking for a script which runs in the background which can provide information about which users uses which amount of resource.

I'd like to know what the load on our server is, `top` only gives me a 'now'-view, I want to be able to check out the load for a period of time.

To make it more detailed, I'd like this per user, and if possible even more specific (which files are used a lot, or database usage, anything I can use to optimise a bit)

I have no clue whether this exists, I can only find some code which only gives my live results, like `top` and `ps`, that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You might be interested in Zabbix: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent or Nagios.

Comment: That looks very complicated to me, something a bit more stupid-proof would be great. Im going to check it out anyway, as soon as I got the time for it, thanks

Comment: Quick pointers only rather than a full guide, the unix standard command for usage reporting is called "sar", "System Activity Reporter" and monitors various things like disk io, cpu etc on a per user basis, from this there were tools like just 'sa' (doesn't exist under linux, check some of the 'see also' commands for sar).  Might be some help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rephrase this question and make it more focused. What you're asking is too broad a question.

#### ideas

- See my answer here for auditing tool ideas: [Commands for determining level of usage of server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75051/commands-for-determining-level-of-usage-of-server/75060#75060).
- For graphing [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) is another tool, but these solutions are frameworks and seem like more than what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at something like grafana and collectd. Collectd will collect resource usage metrics and send it to grafana so you can have current and historic graphs