# What information about a process is retrievable after it is terminated?

Tags: linux, process, logs, process-management

After a process has been terminated, is it possible to retrieve any information about it, such as when it started and finished, &c.

Is it possible to enable logging of this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, only if you log it at the time. Probably the most straightforward way would be to use the kernel's auditing features using [auditd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd), and configure the system calls that you care about logging.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the list of tools I covered on this U&L Q&A: titled: [Commands for determining level of usage of server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75051/commands-for-determining-level-of-usage-of-server/75060#75060). This answer covered [auditd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) as @ChrisDown highlighted plus several other tools for tracking usage after the fact, such as `sar`, `lastcomm`, and process accounting, among others.