# kernel event listener

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, process-management, application

I wonder if there is something similar to an event listener in UNIX that a program can subscribe to?  Specifically I want to know:

```
Start and end times of a user session
Start and end of the applications executed by that user
```

Any Tips?

Answer (score 1):

#### Using psacct

The events that you're looking for can be found through [psacct](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/). Specifically I'd take a look at the tool `ac` which shows accounting information on users. I touch on this in this U&L Q&A titled: [Commands for determining level of usage of server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75051/commands-for-determining-level-of-usage-of-server/75060#75060).

**NOTE:** This is not a subscribe-able "service", rather a tracking & reporting infrastructure that you can ask it questions.

You can also use `lastcomm` (part of psacct, it has several tools in the suite) to find out when a given application was used by user X.

#### Example

```
$ lastcomm rm
rm                S     root     pts/0      0.00 secs Tue Nov 14 00:39
rm                S     root     pts/0      0.00 secs Tue Nov 14 00:39
rm                S     root     pts/0      0.00 secs Tue Nov 14 00:38
```

You'll have to dig a bit into `psacct` but there's a lot of resources about it on U&L as well as google which should get you what you want.

#### Using auditd

The other tool, in the same vain as `psacct`'s tracking & reporting approach is [`auditd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd). With `auditd` you can query to find out who and for how long program X was run.

#### Example

```
$ sudo ausearch -x /usr/bin/sudo | head -5
----
time->Sat Dec  7 21:15:15 2013
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1386468915.558:419): pid=2189 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="saml" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
----
time->Sat Dec  7 21:15:15 2013
```

**NOTE:** The above is finding all the entries where someone ran the tool `/usr/bin/sudo`.

#### References

- [Chapter 34. Introducing an Audit Rule Set](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/security/html/book.security/cha.audit.scenarios.html)
- [7.7. Searching the Audit Log Files](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Searching_the_Audit_Log_Files.html)