# log files in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, logs, firewall, systemd, rsyslog

In CentOS 7, how can I locate and view all the system logs that tell me who tried to enter the system, who got in, what processes they contacted, what they accomplished, etc.  I want to be able to link every activity to either a userid or a remote IP address.

My `var/log/` directory contains numerous resources including `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/secure`, but most of the files are of type `Binary (application/octet-stream)` and the OS does not know how to open them unless I associate some unknown viewing program with them.  Also, `var/log/firewalld` does not seem to contain useful information.

I can find all the logs produced by my app, my database, and NginX/Apache.

Comment: Ok, you found `/var/log` and al of them are Binaries? you sure? How are you checking?

Comment: @Braiam I did not say they were all binaries.  I said most of them are binaries.  For example, `/var/log/firewalld` is a text file that seems to contain useless information.  I am checking by clicking on the files in the GUI.  First left clicking to try to open, then right clicking to view properties to check file type.

Comment: The system doesn't do this by default. You have to enable audit logging to get this. I show many of the methods in this A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75051/commands-for-determining-level-of-usage-of-server. There's a good overview of auditd here: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/. Search for others, there are many.

Comment: @slm I read your links. Thank you. This will be a web server. I will need to track the identity of every individual who touches in any way any record in a database or any file in specific parts of the file system. I will also need to use this logging data to set up alerts that fire any time an unauthorized user accesses any data. I know how to do the application-and-database-level logging. I want to set up logging so that CentOS logs can be linked to the web container logs, app logs, and database logs, perhaps by ip. How should I frame questions about the CentOS level of this requirement?

Comment: @CodeMed - I'd state that it's CentOS 7, just as you have. I think you can do what you want using auditd, wrt the manipulation of the filesystem and what commands/processes are invoked by users on the local filesystem. This won't show anything beyond user nginx,apache,etc. doing X though from the application level. You might need to blend the 2 together. I would also frame it as a systemd Q, with CentOS 7 being the specific instance.

Comment: @CodeMed - auditd logs to a file, I'm not sure if it can log to a database, I'd suspect that there's a way to do this that's off the shelf, IMO.

Comment: @slm I asked a much narrower question yesterday, but I do not seem to be getting an answer to it.  Are you willing to help me with it?  here is the link:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171335/viewing-firewalld-logs-via-remote-login-to-centos-7-server

Comment: For completeness, in CentOS 6 they're in `/var/log/nginx` FWIW :)

Answer (score 12):

The (commandline) utility you should be using is `journalctl`. E.g. to look at the the dmesg output:

```
journalctl --dmesg
```

or parseable entries relating to the firewall:

```
journalctl --output=json-pretty UNIT=firewalld.service
```

For a list of selectable UNIT use the usual tools:

```
journalctl --output=json-pretty | grep -F UNIT | sort -u
```

See `man journalctl` on your system for more options to restrict and specify the output.

Comment: Thank you.  This is a start.  But my question is more global.  How do I get a list of all available logs? And how do I get the output into a format I can use?  For example, a resource that can be imported into a java program that is tracked to a user or ip.  `journalcdt --dmesg` does not seem to identify anyone more specific than `localhost.localdoman`, and `journalctl --firewalld` produces `unrecognized option`.  So your suggestion does not really answer my question yet.

Comment: You should really look at the man page. It is pretty infromative. `journalctl --output=json-pretty UNIT=firewalld.service` gives you json output.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I did read the manual, but your answer can make it easier to apply.  Right now, `journalctl --output=json-pretty | grep -f UNIT | sort -u` gives `grep: UNIT: No such file or directory`

Comment: Also, `journalctl --output=json-pretty UNIT=firewalld.service` only works when I am logged in as root, but not when I try to use the terminal as a normal user. So I cannot use this code programmatically yet.  If I could somehow auto-generate a fresh set of log files for every selectable unit without having to leave my root password in a hackable file, then this question would be answered.

Comment: @CodeMed There was a typo in the `grep` arguments ( I didn't cut and paste and lowercased the `-F` option).

Comment: I have a follow up question about firewalld logs.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171335/viewing-firewalld-logs-via-remote-login-to-centos-7-server