# viewing firewalld logs via remote login to CentOS 7 server

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, firewalld

I have firewalld installed in a remote CentOS server.  When I log into the server over the internet as root, I type the following command to access the firewalld logs:

```
journalctl --output=json-pretty UNIT=firewalld.service
```

The result is a few records indicating when the service was turned on, etc.

**How do I get the list of attempts that remote users tried to connect with the server?**  Including ip addresses, whether or not they where blocked by firewalld, what they were requesting, what ports, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no logging specified in the firewall rule that rejects the connection attempts, then nothing will appear in the log.

I suggest you read the [RedHat firewalld reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html#Configuring_Complex_Firewall_Rules_with_the_Rich-Language_Syntax) which discusses adding logging requirements to firewall rules. Unfortunately, it's fairly complex and there are no shortcuts that I know of.